# CSS files "not found" with default Wordpress .htaccess settings

Tags: php, css, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I inherited a Wordpress project.

I added a CSS file to theme (e.g. `extra.css`).

But if I try to load it in the browser like so:

`http://example.com/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/extra.css`

I get a 'page not found' error.  The file IS on the server in that directory.

If I create a new folder in the theme folder and try the URL, like so:

`http://example.com/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/test/test.txt`

The text file loads fine.  I can't understand why ONLY CSS files won't load from the filesystem.  I checked the .htaccess file - and the settings are the WP default.

So how can I get WP to recognize new CSS files in this instance?  Or what might be the cause of this issue?

UPDATE:
Two factors may be influencing this: (1) this is a virtual server managed by cPanel (ugh), and (2) the Wordpress theme is Avada by Theme Fusion, which seems to add a lot of strange bloat to the site.

.htaccess contents:

```
# BEGIN custom php.ini PHP54
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home/example/public_html
</IfModule>
# END custom php.ini

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What's your htaccess look like? Can you browse to `thtp://example.com/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/style.css` (the built-in Theme stylesheet)?

Comment: Yes, I can browse to that file.  I will add the .htaccess contents above.

Comment: Your htaccess is not doing anything to prevent access to that file.  I'm suspecting something like a typo in the file name / path, or an obscure character in the file name.  Are you sure there's no htaccess inside the theme folder, or wp-content folder?

Answer (score -1):

You can add this link into your header with proper file location

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

get_template_directory_uri() will go upto your theme
go to header.php
add

```
<link href="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/extra.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

inside title tag
so it will be

```
<title>
  <link href="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/extra.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</title>
```

Comment: What value does this add? OP indicates that the issue has to do with a file not resolving, even though it exists?